# How to get Product Version of Microsoft Sql Server from .mdf file Header using C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to get Product Version of Microsoft Sql Server from .mdf file Header using C# code.I have to open .mdf file and have to read product version from .mdf file header.
product version means 11.0.2100.60 and 10.50.1600.0 like this.Not like this 8,9,10,11 and 661 ,705,611..

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(mdffile))
               {
                   using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                   {
                       br.ReadBytes(9 * 8192 + 96 + 4);
                       byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(2);
                       dbiVersion = buffer[0] + 256 * buffer[1];
                   }
                   fs.Close();
               }
```

Comment: using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(mdffile))
               {
                   using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                   {
                       br.ReadBytes(9 * 8192 + 96 + 4);
                       byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(2);
                       dbiVersion = buffer[0] + 256 * buffer[1];
                   }
                   fs.Close();
               }

Comment: Code in a comment stinks.

Comment: Vembu, please edit your post rather than putting it in the comments!

Comment: In the above code in dbiVersion i am getting 661,706 ,705 like this.

Comment: Looks like there may be a better way of doing it using SMO's DatabaseFile class and then the GetVersionName method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.databasefile.aspx

Comment: Ya by using that class we can find the server version if .mdf file is attached in the server.now my purpose is i have to find Sql server version from .mdf file header and have to attach .mdf file with that particular server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
string mdfFileName = args[0];

if (!File.Exists(mdfFileName))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: specified file does not exist!");
    return;
}

NameValueCollection mdfFileVersions = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MdfFileVersions") as NameValueCollection;

try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(mdfFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

    // skip the first 0x12064 bytes
    reader.ReadBytes(0x12064);

    // read two bytes
    short fileVersion = reader.ReadInt16();
    string sqlServerVersion = string.Empty;

    if (mdfFileVersions != null)
    {
        sqlServerVersion = mdfFileVersions[fileVersion.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlServerVersion))
        {
            sqlServerVersion = "unknown version";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sqlServerVersion = "no version info available";
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Examined file: '{0}'", mdfFileName);
    Console.WriteLine("File version : {0} ({1})", fileVersion, sqlServerVersion);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: cannot open specified MDF file");
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}", exc.GetType().FullName, exc.Message);
}
```

and I have defined the file versions to look for in my `app.config` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="MdfFileVersions" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>
    <MdfFileVersions>
        <add key="515" value="SQL Server 7" />
        <add key="539" value="SQL Server 2000" />
        <add key="616" value="SQL Server 2005 (up to SP1)" />
        <add key="612" value="SQL Server 2005 (SP2 and newer)" />
        <add key="655" value="SQL Server 2008 (up to SP1)" />
        <add key="661" value="SQL Server 2008 R2" />
        <add key="705" value="SQL Server 2012 RC0" />
        <add key="706" value="SQL Server 2012" />
        <add key="782" value="SQL Server 2014" />
    </MdfFileVersions>
</configuration>
```

This makes it easily extensible - once newer versions come out, just add another entry in your config file, and your done!

Comment: Hai any code to get server version like 11.0.2100.60 from mdf file header because there are more versions in the sql server 2012 and 2008 ....

Comment: @Vembu: no, the `.mdf` file only contains a **file version** number - 515, 661, etc. - they don't contain the **server** software version...